# Material-UI: Trigger hover effect programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am rendering the following `Material-UI` component in my app:

```
const handleSetActive = _spyOn => {
  linkEl.current.focus();
};

const linkEl = useRef(null);

return (
    <ListItem
      button
      component={SmoothScrollLink}
      to={cutTo}
      spy
      smooth
      offset={(phone ? -theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeightPhone : -theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeightDesktop) - 20}
      duration={500}
      onSetActive={handleSetActive}
      // className={classNames(spyOn === cutTo && classes.hover)}
      ref={linkEl}
      {...other}
    />
)
```

It is using the [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) package which fires `onSetActive` whenever one scrolls past that particular `ListItem`.

I would like, in the simplest way possible, to make `ListItem` ([from Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/)) enable its hover effect when `handleSetActive` fires.

How would I best accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the portions of the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L67) related to the `ListItem` hover state:

```
export const styles = theme => ({
  /* Styles applied to the (normally root) `component` element. May be wrapped by a `container`. */
  root: {
    '&$selected, &$selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected,
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the inner `component` element if `button={true}`. */
  button: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('background-color', {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
    '&:hover': {
      textDecoration: 'none',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
      // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
      '@media (hover: none)': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the root element if `selected={true}`. */
  selected: {},
});
```

Since in your case you have `button={true}`, the styling you want can be achieved by a CSS class that applies the following:

```
      textDecoration: 'none',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
```

Here's a sandbox that shows using the `activeClass` property for react-scroll's `Link` to apply a class with this styling: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactscroll-gppym.

Here's another sandbox using a ref to apply the class directly on the DOM node: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactscroll-using-ref-9w8ki; however you shouldn't use this approach (showing it for learning purposes only) since it does more work (would perform worse) than the `activeClass` approach and is very brittle since a re-render for other reasons could wipe out the class applied via the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Would you set state in handleSetActive, then use className with classNames to conditionally apply the style when depending on the state?

Comment: It felt a bit unnatural to have to create state here, when I already have a handler that fires at the right spot. Is it possible to avoid state by using a ref somehow?

Comment: Yes, you could avoid state by just toggling the class directly in the DOM with a ref for the ListItem. That will work fine so long as your app doesn’t need to know which item is active for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Could you help me with an example of how to do that? I am struggling

Comment: Sure. Please create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with a working example of the key aspects of your setup (i.e. list items using react-scroll with onSetActive/Inactive), and I'll enhance it to show toggling the class.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, Ryan. The code sandbox is here, using the state approach for the time being (which is not fully finished and is not fast enough when scrolling): https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsbystarterdefault-290qv

Comment: I read up on refs, but still could not get it to work. Is it possible that react-scroll does not forward the refs to the underlying DOM element?

Comment: Sorry for the spam here. Two updates: 1) I changed the CodeSandbox to use refs. 2) I guess the ref should not actually be forwarded to the underlying DOM node in this case. Instead it should be pointing to the MUI component (ListItem), right? Because that's the one we want to set the style on? So, it seems the ref is forwarded by MUI to the underlying `react-scroll` Link component, instead of pointing to the outer MUI component (ListItem).

Comment: I added a sandbox. I did not base it on yours just because there was a fair amount going on in yours that was unrelated to the problem. Instead of using a ref, I used the `activeClass` property in react-scroll's `Link`.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks. Yes, I found the `activeClass` as well. Was there any way to do it with refs (just for learning purposes), or did I spot the correct problem above?

Comment: I've added another sandbox using a ref, but after looking at the implementation details of react-scroll, I do not recommend going this route. It won't perform better and it won't be as reliable.

Comment: Thank you. Where can i find the link to the sandbox?

Comment: At the end of my answer.